# Iterating a list with hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

I have userTable

uid username password
1   stephen   1542S
2   james     8452b

**Store procedure name:** sp_gridview 
**query:** select * from userTable

```
List list=null; 
list=hibernateTemplate.
getSessionFactory().openSession()
.createSQLQuery("call sp_gridview").list();

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

here i am not using generics because, that not needed for my requirements.
i try to iterate above list but, it show result is hash code.

```
output: [Ljava.lang.Object;@3c668d12.
```

how i iterate a list and get a value without hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're getting an `Object` back, and `Object.toString()` which is called when trying to print it prints that. To solve it, you can cast it to the actual type of the `Object` to get a specific `toString()` method. As such:

```
System.out.println((String)list.get(i));
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response pescis. but it didn't work, now

Comment: i get this exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: What do you have in the list? Cast it to that, and not String.